# trying to scrape data from html code using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been making a web scraper for a website and I am wanting to extract all the node numbers from a html table using .findall or something that will work but I am struggling to get it, I am constantly getting errors I am clearly not putting in the right tags.

Can anyone help, the html code is as follows

```
</div>

<table class="dataTable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNodes" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="header noBreak">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl00','')">Node Name</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl01','')">Description</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl02','')">MAC Address</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl03','')"></a>
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$liNodeRoleHeader','')" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNodes_ctl00_liNodeRoleHeader">Node Role</a>
            </td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl04','')">Firmware</a></td><td>
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$lbUptimeHeader','')" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNodes_ctl00_lbUptimeHeader">Uptime</a>
            </td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl05','')">Users</a></td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.className = 'highlightedRow';" onmouseout="this.className = 'normalRow';" onclick="GoToNodePage('522');" style="height:18px;">
```

I need to extract the number 522 on the last line of code and all other gotonodepage numbers but I cant figure it out, any help is appreciated. I also want to put the extracted numbers into a list of later use.

```
r2 = s2.get(webpage)
bsobjswap = BeautifulSoup(r2.content)

listy = []
for link in bsobjswap.findall('tr'):
    if 'onclick' in link.attrs:
        listy.append(link)
print (listy)
```

error is
   for link in bsobjswap.findall('tr'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Your code ? The error messages ?

Comment: webpage = "mycompanywebsite.com"
    r2 = s2.get(webpage)
    bsobjswap = BeautifulSoup(r2.content)
    
    listy = []
    for link in bsobjswap.findall('tr'):
        if 'onclick' in link.attrs:
            listy.append(link)
    print (listy)

Comment: errors are the standard TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable, obviously because the code is wrong and im not finding any data

Comment: Not in comments, edit your question.

Comment: sorry there you go

Comment: Where do you see that `findall` is a valid method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """<table class="dataTable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNodes" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="header noBreak">
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl00','')">Node Name</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl01','')">Description</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl02','')">MAC Address</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl03','')"></a>
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$liNodeRoleHeader','')" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNodes_ctl00_liNodeRoleHeader">Node Role</a>
            </td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl04','')">Firmware</a></td><td>
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$lbUptimeHeader','')" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNodes_ctl00_lbUptimeHeader">Uptime</a>
            </td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgNodes$ctl00$ctl05','')">Users</a></td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.className = 'highlightedRow';" onmouseout="this.className = 'normalRow';" onclick="GoToNodePage('522');" style="height:18px;">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
print([i.get('onclick') for i in soup.findAll('tr', attrs={'onclick':True})])
```

This will return `["GoToNodePage('522');"]`

From here you can extract the number with regex for example

```
print([re.findall("\d+", i.get('onclick')) for i in soup.findAll('tr', attrs={'onclick':True})])
```

This will return `[['522']]`

Comment: thanks Gábor Erdős that worked perfectly, one question how can I get the result to go into a list, something I seem to struggling with quite alot

Comment: nevermind think i figures it out

Comment: Actually the result of this is a nested list. You get a list out of `findAll` of `BeautifullSoup` and from `findall` of `re` as well. So the result will be a list in a list. If a `tr` tag may only contain one `onclick` attribute you can switch the `findall` of `re` to a simple `find`, and you will end up with a list. It depends on the problem (whole xml)

Comment: thanks Gábor Erdős, can you help me with one other thing, I need to get it to a point where the nodenumbers are just on there own so I can append them onto a url such www.companysite.com?NodeID=522 that sort of thing but when I try and attach them together I get TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: Use `result[0]` for example (assuming you store the output in variable `result`). That will give you the 0th (first) element of the list. If its a nested list `result[0][0`] will give you the 0th (first) element of the 0th (first) inner list of the outer list